# Words for places to live (besides house)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Where I live (northeast Brazil) we have the following:

- Apartment (*Apartamento* in portuguese)

The general word for a set of bedrooms + kitchen + bathrooms + living room in an apartment condominium. Usually it has at least two bedrooms, but that's not necessary - I guess this is what it  means anywhere.

- Flat (*Flat* too - we borrowed it)

Usually a makes you think of a small apartment. Hardly ever you would call it a flat if it has more than two bedrooms.

- *Quitinete* (That's Portuguese already)

This is a place for one person. It's practically always very small, with a single main room that works as a bedroom, kitchen and living room altogether (It also has a bathroom, sure).

So what I would like to ask is:

1. What words would you use for these in AE and in BE?
2. What are the meanings of flat and loft?
3. What other kinds of places for living are there? Could you explain that in some details?

Comment: At first I thought you were looking for a general term to cover all varieties, which would be [dwelling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dwelling).  Instead, it looks like you are wanting a list of all possible types of dwelling, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: Other places for living? Hotels, hostels, quarters, motels, caravans and plenty more. What is the purpose of your list-preparation? I'm curious

Comment: @cobaltduck I agree that item 3 *is* off-topic as an open-ended question, not suited to the SE format. For the rest, the various requests in this question are closely related and shouldn't be stretching the bounds too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AE: 
A quitinete in Portuguese comes from the word in English kitchenette, in fact. We say studio apartment or efficiency. An efficiency or studio apartment has a kitchenette (a small kitchen).

Brazilian Portuguese took the word for kitchenette, made quitinete, as a synedoche for a studio or efficiency (apartment). A funny thing: the old efficiencies in New  York City often had beds that folded up into the wall. Flat (UK) is apartamento, of any kind. In the US, we say apartment for an apartamento. We also refer to apartments as being condos when they are in a condominium property. "I have a condo in Florida" = I have an apartment in a condominium building in Florida.

A loft is very different. It refers to large, (usually) open-plan apartment made from reconverted warehouse-type buildings in large cities (usually) like New York or Los Angeles.

Comment: What's the difference between a condo and an apartment - is it the fact that it can be owned individually? In Britain, flats are nearly always owned individually (and then occupied by the owner or a private tenant) - I'm sure there are examples of a single person or corporation owning an entire block of flats, but that would not be very common at all. All new-build apartment blocks, in London certainly, have marketing suites attached to attract individual buyers.

Comment: @CharlE They are usually owned on long leases of 99 or 999 years. So what you buy is the remainder of the lease. The "service rent" is usually a nominal amount. Legally you are entitled to re-instate the length of the lease to its original term at any time, upon calculation of a fee based on a regulated formula.

Comment: An apartment is a generic term that is the opposite (in housing terms) of a single house. A condo is a type of ownership in a property that has a bunch of apartments (or at least two). In a condo, you own your apartment and pay a fee to the owners' association for common charges. The same thing exists in England, different terminology which I am loathe to look up at this point.

Answer (score 2):

In BE:

A ***flat*** can mean any kind of apartment from the smallest one-room place to the largest; as long as it is in a building along with other units, it can be called a flat. You could refer to a *one-bedroom flat*, a *two-bedroom flat*, a *five-bedroom, two-bathroom flat* and so on.

A ***bed-sit*** (from *bedroom + sitting room*) is a flat consisting of one main room only, with a kitchen and sleeping/reception area combined; usually has a separate shower/toilet facility. Typically occupied by young singles or students.

The word ***apartment*** is used in Britain, but usually only by estate agents (realtors) trying to exaggerate the desirability of a flat.

Comment: Not forgetting *bungalow*, *maisonette*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In AE:
An apartment has the same meaning, with the added provision that you pay monthly rent to live there.

A studio apartment would be your quitinete, though here you usually have a single main room plus a small kitchen, and you may have an open loft for storage or to house your bed.

A condo is like an apartment in every respect, except that you own your unit.  You pay a mortgage, maintenance on the building is prorated among the various owners, etc.

A townhome is similar to a condo.  Usually a townhome has very few units per building (sometimes just two units), and each unit has a small garage instead of shared parking lot.  You may share a driveway with other units.

We don't use "flat" for anything.

Edited to add that the US will have regional differences as well.  I've read plenty of books (especially mystery novels) that refer to characters living in "a brownstone," something I'd never heard of here in the south; the novels were set in New York.  That's just one example.  I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Sorry, but the open loft for storage is confusing to me. it's really an unusual feature, and is usually in a house, not most apartments, except for those fancy two-level things where the top level is billed a loft. That is very different from a loft apartment.

Comment: Yes, those are two different things.  A storage loft isn't uncommon here in studio apartments.  It's not the same thing as living in a loft, as you said.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My experience of studios in NYC and the NE doesn't include storage lofts....maybe in other parts of the country??

Comment: With no evidence whatsoever, I'd guess it's down to the age of the building.  Or if the building was converted from a hotel or office building and had high ceilings, or if it became a new selling feature, etc.  Just like a trend I'm noticing here in new single-family homes is to give each bedroom a private bathroom.  That would be unheard of in most neighborhoods.

Comment: Oh, there are plenty of "flats" appearing around DC, but it's just used as marketing term, leading to irritating redundancies like [The Flats at Dupont Circle Apartments](http://www.equityapartments.com/washington-dc/dupont-circle/the-flats-at-dupont-circle-apartments) and the [Federal Flats Apartments](http://federalflats.com/), or the even more absurd [Flats and Warehouses at Union Row](http://www.lifeatthetop.com/condo/unionrow), which of course are neither flats nor warehouses. Also, a *studio* may be an *efficiency* or a *bachelor* in some areas.

Comment: Gees, I remember when Dupont Circle was the cut-off point (west of it)  for where it was "desirable" to live. Now, it's all been gentrified. DC is still the weirdest city....government people, diplomats and many disadvantaged locals.